# Editing feature class using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, feature-class, editing

I am working with some feature classes. I create those feature classes using my add-in. User can add/ delete features from these feature classes clicking on "add", "delete" buttons and selecting features. I added features using following code:

```
void AddFeature(IFeatureClass featureClass, IGeometry geometry)
{
    IFeature feature = featureClass.CreateFeature();
    feature.Shape = geometry;
    feature.Store();
}
```

And deleted features using following code:

```
void DeleteFeaturesWithinPolygon(IFeatureClass featureClass, IPolygon polygon)
{
    List<IFeature> features = GetFeaturesWithinPolygon(featureClass, polygon);
    foreach (var feature in features)
        feature.Delete();
}
```

Thing is, I did not use editor session. And actually, I did not think about it earlier. but today seeing [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49056/how-to-cancel-saveedits-stopedits-button-press-arcobjects/49211#49211), I think about edit session. I know can do these edits, without edit session. Actually I am doing it right now.

Comment: After doing work with `IEditor`, I feel that most amazing thing of this is decreasing significant amount of time. When I updated 13k features, time reduces from 20 minutes to 1 minute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this document will provide to you a good source of knowledge:
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000340000000

Answer (score 6):

I recommend starting and finishing all edits within an edit operation inside of a `try` block, where a `catch` block would call [AbortOperation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/AbortOperation_Method/0020000000s3000000/).

Something I've always wondered about is whether it makes sense before starting an edit operation to check to see if there's already an operation underway, via [IWorkspaceEdit2.IsInEditOperation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IsInEditOperation_Property/002500000m60000000/).

Comment: But if I do edit in the way I am doing now, is it wrong or is there any kind of problem?

Answer (score 5):

The benefit of starting an edit session is that you can use the many different [edit event listeners](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Working_with_editing_events/000100000154000000/) to control edit workflow if needed.  You also have the ability to undo edits if a feature was deleted by mistake.